# Single field , multi-record Data-aware control

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, delphi-7, data-aware

I trying to create a data-aware component that is a single field  , multi-record control , something like TDBLoookupList , but with the KeyField only.
I cannot figure how to iterate through the dataset correctly .

```
 private  
   FFieldDataLink:TFieldDataLink;
   FDataList:Tlist;

 if FFieldDataLink.DataSet.Active and (FFieldDataLink.FieldName<>'' ) then
 begin
   try
      FFieldDataLink.DataSet.GetFieldList(FFDataList,FieldDataLink.FieldName);
   except  
     DatabaseErrorFmt(SFieldNotFound, [Self.Name,FFieldDataLink.FieldName]);
   end;
 end;
```

the above code snippet should return a list of the fields in the buffer, but it returns only the first record .

thanks

Comment: I noticed you snipped this from the Delphi source.. I don't think this is the correct direction to take. Have you read up on `TFieldDataLink`? Are you wanting to create a component that has two properties in the IDE's Object Inspector called `Datasource` and `KeyField`, and the `Keyfield` property is a list of fields contained in the `Datasource`?  If this is the case, I can help you, but Ineed more clarification, and we can edit your question to be more clear..

Comment: I believe [GetFieldList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.GetFieldList) does not what you expect.

Comment: Are you aware of `TDBCtrlGrid`?  It is a multi-record control and whether it is single-field is up to you.  Btw, once you have a reference to the dataset via your FFieldDataLink, you can iterate it in the usual way with a `while not DataSet.Eof ..Next` loop.

Comment: Martin , if i iterated using while , i' ll get the values but lose the link.

Comment: John , i didn't snip from Delphi source , i created my component guided by TdblookuoList , the sole example on the planet that use a singke filed multirecord approach. I want to create sonera sort of a dataaware tlistbox.

Comment: @DrWael why not just descend your component from TdbLookupList?  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: John Easley , because of two things : first in an inherited  class we can remove a class member, and i just need the keyfield not the lookupfield. Second i already had written an advanced version of Tlistbox , and i now i want to add database support to it :)